# SPLIT results with separator

Tags: string, abap

I'm trying to split a string (separated with the HTML break tag), without deleting the break tag. I think it's pretty messy to add a break as string after splitting, so is there any function/possibility to keep the separator while "splitting"?

Example:

```
<HTML><BODY><p>some text<br/>some more text</p></BODY></HTML>
```

Expected result:

```
<HTML><BODY><p>some text<br/>
some more text</p></BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: I have edited your question to provide an example (the one from Dirk so that to keep his answer consistent)

Comment: Is the "expected result" to be an "internal table" of lines, or a string with a "newline" character inserted after each `<br/>` or something else? What did you try up to now?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know `SPLIT` removes the separator from the results and it doesn't seem like you can change that.

But you could create your own separator by first replacing your `<br/>` tag with `<br/>` plus an arbitrary string that is highly unlikely to ever appear in your HTML source, and then split the HTML using this arbitrary string as a separator instead.

```
types:
  begin of t_result,
    segment(2000) type c,
  end of t_result.

DATA:
  source type string,
  separator type string,
  brtag type string,
  repl type string,
  result_tab type standard table of t_result,
  result_row TYPE t_result.

brtag = '<br/>'.
separator = '|***SEP***|'.
concatenate brtag separator into repl.
source = '<HTML><BODY><p>some text<br/>some more text</p></BODY></HTML>'.

replace all occurrences of brtag in source with repl.
split source at separator into table result_tab.

LOOP AT result_tab INTO result_row.
  WRITE:
  result_row-segment.
ENDLOOP.
```

Output of that example report:

```
<HTML><BODY><p>some text<br/>
some more text</p></BODY></HTML>
```

The caveat of this solution is that your custom separator, if not chosen with some care, might appear in your HTML source on its own. I therefore would choose an arbitrary string with a special character or two that would be encoded in HTML (like umlauts) and therefore not appear in your source.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the replace command. replace `<br/>` with `<br/>CR_LF`
The CR_LF refers to the carriage return linefeed character.
In more complex cases you can use regex expressions in abap.

```
class ZTEST_SO definition   public    create public .
public section.
methods t1.
ENDCLASS.
CLASS ZTEST_SO IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD T1.
     data: my_break type string,
            my_string type string
                    value '<HTML><BODY><p>some text<br/>some more text</p></BODY></HTML>'.

     my_break = '<br/>' && CL_ABAP_CHAR_UTILITIES=>CR_LF.
     replace all occurrences of '<br/>' in my_string with my_break in character mode.
     "check my_string in the debugger :)

     "<HTML><BODY><p>some text<br/>
     "some more text</p></BODY></HTML>
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```